# can't edit input with prop value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a string , in certain places I need to insert input tags with values. Everything displays fine , but I can't delete or edit values in input. What is wrong with that input?

```
editModalText() {
    let modalMessage="Hello, my name is /# Ann #/. I'm working for /# IStaff #/, could you please call me back"

    return (
      <div>
        {modalMessage
          .split("/")
          .map((text, idx) =>
            text.includes("#") ? this.replaceCharacter(idx, text) : text,
          )}
      </div>
    )
  }


replaceCharacter(idx, text) {
    let formattedText = text.replace(/#/g, " ")

    return (
      <input
        key={idx}
        value={formattedText}
        onChange={e => this.setState({input:e.target.value})}
      />
    )
  }
```

Comment: you can only set state in Class components, here you have a function a.k.a. stateless component, hence, you don't have `setState`. You can use hooks if you like https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: @fila90 It is in class component , I'm just showing functions

Answer (score 0):

replace `value={formattedText}` with `defaultValue={formattedText}`

this way input will be editable. it will show default value on first render and as you type you'll store that value in your state.

you can read more about controlled and uncontrolled components in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to bind the input value and the state together. I am not sure how you're currently calling `replaceCharacter` but I would do something like this :

```
replaceCharacter(idx) {    
    return (
      <input
        key={idx}
        value={this.state.input.replace(/#/g, " ")}
        onChange={e => this.setState({input:e.target.value})}
      />
    )
  }
```

This way when you update your state with the `onChange` event the value of the state will be populated in the input.